# Exception when using @Query Annotation - "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: declarative query methods are a todo"

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

I'm new to Spring-data-cassandra. My sample code looks something like this:

Customer.java

```
@Table
public class Customer {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @CassandraType(type = Name.BIGINT)
    private Long age;

    protected Customer() {}

    public Customer(String id, String firstName, String lastName, Long age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Long getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%s, firstName='%s', lastName='%s', age=%d]",
                id, firstName, lastName, age);
    }
}
```

CustomerRepository.java

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    @Query("select * from customer where lastname = :lName")
    List<Customer> findByLastName(@Param("lName") String lName);
    List<Customer> findAll();
}
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

        repository.save(new Customer("0", "Jack", "Bauer", 20L));
        repository.save(new Customer("1", "Chloe", "O'Brian", 21L));
        repository.save(new Customer("2", "Kim", "Bauer", 22L));
        repository.save(new Customer("3", "David", "Palmer", 23L));
        repository.save(new Customer("4", "Michelle", "Dessler", 24L));


        // fetch all customers
        System.out.println("Customers found with findAll():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : repository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }

        // fetch customers by last name                                                                                                                                                                             
        System.out.println("Customer found with findByLastName('Bauer'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        for (Customer bauer : repository.findByLastName("Bauer")) {
            System.out.println(bauer);
        }


        System.out.println("Done.");
    }    
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>mine.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I get the following exception when I try to run the code:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: mine.samples.CustomerRepository mine.samples.Application.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: declarative query methods are a todo
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at mine.samples.Application.main(Application.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: mine.samples.CustomerRepository mine.samples.Application.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: declarative query methods are a todo
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: declarative query methods are a todo
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: declarative query methods are a todo
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.CassandraRepositoryFactory$CassandraQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(CassandraRepositoryFactory.java:115)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:369)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:192)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:225)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.CassandraRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraRepositoryFactoryBean.java:62)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

The gist of the exception is that "declarative query methods are a todo". The documentation is a little unclear on what is and what isn't supported. Could anyone shed light on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was importing the wrong `@Query` in `CustomerRepository.java`. I fixed it by changing the import to:

```
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.Query;
```